# Pinescript elif function

Tags: if-statement, pine-script

I tried creating an elif statement in Pinescript but it came out as error. Can anyone please help?

```
trend_1 = sma(close, 60)
trend_2 = sma(close, 30)
trend_3 = sma(close, 15)

if bar_index >= 252
    trend := trend_1
else if bar_index < 252 and >= 126
    trend := trend_2
else 
    trend := trend_3
```

Mismatched input 'if' expecting 'end of line without line continuation'.

Answer (score 1):

The error is misleading. You forgot to supply the left argument for the `>=` operator:

`else if bar_index < 252 and >= 126`

Add another `bar_index` there and it should work:

`else if bar_index < 252 and bar_index >= 126`